# Arrow function with Square Brackets?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am working on some code, and I have stumbled across something I am unfamiliar with.

```
export const doSomething = () => [ someFunction(), bind(stuff, stuff, stuff) ];
```

I have never seen an arrow function with a square bracket like that, has anyone else? If so what is the meaning of how it works?

Comment: Doesn't it just return an array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code means that your function `doSomething` returns an array when

`[0]` element - the result of execution of function `someFunction()` and

`[1]` element - the result of execution of function `bind(stuff, stuff, stuff)`.

This is a shortcut for:

```
export const doSomething = () => {
    return [ someFunction(), bind(stuff, stuff, stuff) ]
};
```

But be careful if you want to make a shortcut for returning objects. You have to wrap objects in parentheses `()`, like this:

`export const doSomething = () => ({ name: 'John' })`.

Answer (score 4):

It's just returning an array.

You might use it with a destructuring assign e.g.

```
const [someResult, boundStuff] = doSomething()
```

Or just like any old function e.g.

```
const something = doSomething()
```